# (data:Any)=>println(data) vs data:Any=>println(data)

Tags: scala, language-lawyer

I came across the following scala code：

```
val x = 10 match {
  case _: Int => data: Any => println(data) // no issue
}

val y = data: Any => println(data) //compiling error
```

In the match case clause, I don't have to write `data: Any => println(data)` as 
`(data: Any) => println(data)`

But in `val y = data: Any => println(data)`, I have to write as `val y = (data: Any) => println(data)`. Why?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Actually, there isn't even a question. What is your question? What is the *concrete* programming problem that you need help with?

Comment: Have you read carefully？If you know the answer, please answer it; if you don't,please give other people a chance to answer, thank you

Comment: Description of a question can't make everyone happy. The two answers that have been posted until now, have exactly answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant rule is

> [If an anonymous function `(x: T) => e` with a single typed parameter appears as the result expression of a block, it can be abbreviated to `x: T => e`.](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions)

The first case (`case _: Int => data: Any => println(data)`) satisfies this condition, the second one doesn't. But you can rewrite it to

```
val y = { data: Any => println(data) }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Difference in one is  case statement with pattern matching another is assignment statement. In the first case we are essentially returning the value(result) of the right hand side of  => as statement block as shown below.

```
scala> {data: Any => println(data)}
res0: Any => Unit = $$Lambda$1141/1699449247@71468613

scala> data: Any => println(data)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '=>' found.
       data: Any => println(data)
scala> val x = 10 match {
     |   case _: Int => val y = 56;data: Any => println(data) // no issue
     | }
x: Any => Unit = $$Lambda$1171/115016870@8f374de
```

The above statements considers everything after => will be considered as a `statement block` in `case` statement, but in the second case ( assignment - ie., assigning a function value ) it is not. Hence brackets around parameter declaration are necessary.

**EDIT:**

Though I have given the above answer as per my observation in scala REPL, I further thought
that it will not clearly answer the Why? part of the question asked. I further did some more
trails on how scala compiler behaves after investigating the exact error message we get when we type

```
val y = data:Int => println(data)

scala> val y = data:Int => println(data)
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '(' found.
       val y = data:Int => println(data)
```

This seems to be due to the scala's feature of type inference of the `val y`.

In Scala `type` can be specified both explicitly wherever it is required and Scala compiler can implicitly `infer type` wherever it can. Here the `type of y` is to be inferred by the scala compiler in the first instance because it was not explicitly declared here. It is due to this attempt of the compiler the above error message occurred.

Now if we want to explicitly declare the `type` there are `two ways` in scala:

**First way**  : `val y : Int = 5`

**Second way** : `val y = 5:Int`

Both of the above assignment statements are `valid` in scala.

Because in our specific assignment statement ie.,

```
val y = data:Any => println(data)
```

we are forcing scala to infer the `type of y` in the ***Second way*** shown above.

To infer the `type of y`, the scala compiler is attempting as explained below:

Here the compiler is assuming that `data` is a function defined somewhere before this line of code and the function is of type `Int=>println(data)`. Then it is checking the validity of this type. The compiler determined that `Int` is a valid type but `println(data)` is not, because the valid type names cannot contain parentheses(`'(' char`) and that is why the `error message` as above.

If we insert the right hand side of the above assignment statement in a block ie; between curly
braces or putting the parameter declaration within parentheses, there will be no problem in  inferring the `type of y`.

Or Using the ***First way***, we can do this to compile without curly braces,

```
val y : Any => Unit = data =>println(data)


scala> val y : Any => Unit = data =>println(data)
y: Any => Unit = $$Lambda$1059/1854873748@799c8758
```

Hope this explains the why part of the question.